# How can I specify path of flowconfig file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I need to have different `.flowconfig` files because in one of them I will need to include `module.file_ext=.web.js` in modules section and in the other file I will need to include `module.file_ext=.native.js`.

This is useful because flow understands routes and will help me to figure if there is a missing file required on the application.

I was looking at the [documentation](https://flowtype.org) but I couldn't find if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it is not possible to override it through the CLI.

`.flowconfig` seems to be hardcoded: [source reference on github](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/src/server/server_files_js.ml#L23)

There also [is an open issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/945) for your problem